# npm install kerberos Clang warning

Tags: c++, node.js, llvm, macos-sierra, libc++

I am hoping for some guidance regarding a warning I receive when I attempt to install kerberos via **npm install kerberos**

clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9

What is the proper way for me to have node link to libc++ rather than libstdc++? I've read that node v7 will link to libc++ but node v7 is not LTS version yet. I have the latest LTS version of node which is v6.10.0, with npm v4.3.0.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!